# Python - how to do not start thread on build thread step

Tags: python, multithreading

**I have this code:**

```
import threading

tokens = [here are list with tokens]

def geter(token):
    print('FROM METHOD')

for token in tokens:
    t = threading.Thread(target=geter(token), args=(token,))
    print('THERE METHOD "GETER" SHOULD NOT RUN')
    t.start()
    print('THERE METHOD "GETER" WAS EXECUTED')
```

I need to start method 'geter' only after 't.start', not on build threads step.

But in my case I see 2 prints after method 'geter' was run.
**I have this print:**

```
FROM METHOD
THERE METHOD "GETER" SHOULD NOT RUN
THERE METHOD "GETER" WAS EXECUTED
```

How to run method 'geter' only between first and second PRINT(on step: t.start())?
**I need this print:**

```
THERE METHOD "GETER" SHOULD NOT RUN
FROM METHOD
THERE METHOD "GETER" WAS EXECUTED
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are invoking (calling) the function instead of passing it to the `Thread` class, so instead of

```
t = threading.Thread(target=geter(token), args=(token,))
```

Do this:

```
t = threading.Thread(target=geter, args=(token,))
```

Notice that you do not need to supply `token` twice, that should have hinted to you that something is wrong.

The `target` argument should be either a function (like `geter`) or `None`, but since you are calling the function right there, which returns `None` (because it's not returning anything) you get no errors. You do however get this unexpected behavior